# How to substitution into word into double quotations and seperated by comma?

Tags: regex, notepad++

i have notepad++ file and i want substitution in word into quotations with comma separated. the data look like this

```
krishna krishna@gmail.com 12312
siva siva@gmail.com 123132
```

this should output like

```
'krishna', 'krishna@gmail.com', '12312'
'siva', 'siva@gmail.com', '12312'
```

after that i have append some text like this:

```
insertinto mysql table('krishna', 'krishna@gmail.com', '12312');
```

with explation i will help us in future. how to solve it.

Thanks in Advance for all suggestions.

Comment: There was the same question yesterday (or 2 days ago).

Comment: yes but i have got some problem solving with that. so i asked again.

Comment: Did you delete that post? You could ask me using a comment. What issue did you have? Please add the details to the question. There were 2 steps: add the quotes (`(^\h*|\h*$)|(\h+)` --> `(?1':',')`), wrap with the SQL command (`.+` -> `insertinto mysql table\($0\);`). What is the issue?

Comment: Do you mean you do not need to do it with Notepad++? You need a PCRE based solution? **Please clarify**.

Comment: Hello Wiktor i tryed your code just now in notepad++, it showing 0 replace took place. Please verify your code with my data. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I pasted the regexps and replacement patterns *after* I verified them in Notepad++ with your data. If a space is required between `,`, use `(?1':', ')` as the first replacement pattern.

Comment: sorry i forgot regex expression radio button to change before replace it. It worked fine thank you. will please explain it or show some links to read it. in future i work on this.

Comment: I have explained that in my previous post. Please consider undeleting it.

Comment: ok Thanks. Can this Regular Expression work in MS Document or not.

Comment: Never, MS Word does not support regex in S&R window, and it can only support weak JavaScript-like regex in VBA. You would need to modify the regexps, and use 3 steps in VBA.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew MS Word has a poor implementation of regular expressions. Expand the "More>>" in the replace dialogue then tick the "Use wildcards" box. Use the dropdown list at "Special" to insert meta symbols. I have used it occasionally, but most times I need to do regular expression work with text in MS Word I move the text to a proper editor (like Notepad++), make the changes, then move the text back.

Comment: @AdrianHHH: Wildcards are not regular expressions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Of course I know that. Please check in MS Word and see *exactly* what they offer. Do some quick experiments. They are providing a form of regular expression (as I said before, a poor implementation). It is accessed via the "Use wildcards" box, but it is not what many people would expect from the term wildcard.

Comment: @AdrianHHH: Even if MS calls their wildcard patterns regex patterns that does not make wildcard patterns regex patterns. Because they cannot match regular language.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes they can. Go and try them. They offer most of the normal regular expression things.

Comment: I still believe [they cannot](http://superuser.com/questions/701201/regular-expression-to-match-zero-or-more-spaces-in-microsoft-word/701223).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in 1 Replace with Regular expression in Notepad++

The regex puts the 3 columns into 3 capture groups.
And then the extra stuff is added to them in the replace.

Find what : `^([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+(\d+)$`
Replace with : `insert into mysqltable\('\1','\2','\3'\);`
Search Mode : Regular expression

[image]

If you don't know the number of columns then you can do that with 3 regex replacements.

1) replace the delimiter (space in this case): find `(?<!^)[ ]+(?!$)` and replace with `','`

2) add to the end : find `\s*$` and replace with  `'\);`
Or with just `'` if you don't want to make into a sql statement.

3) add to the start : find `^\s*` and replace with  `insert into mysqltable\('`
Or with just `'` if you don't want to make into a sql statement.

Comment: the number of columns may increase or decrease. you are just fixing it.

Comment: Added a solution for when the number of colums isn't fixed.

Comment: your code working fine. can you tell me words into quotations simple regex replacements

Comment: it fixed the problem. i want to know a word into substitution  into quotation with first word also. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated it again. For when you don't want to make it into a SQL immediatly. Same principle anyway.

Comment: Also, to just get them comma-separated with quotes: replace `(\S+)[ ]*` with `'$1'`, then `''` with `','`

Comment: Thanks its working. Is there any site to learn more about regex expressions

Comment: I often experimented with the javascript flavor on [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/). It has a reference that explains most of the syntax quite well. And [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) if you want to test the pcre flavor. (for example, php supports negative lookbehinds, while javascript does not).

Comment: how to join multiple lines (or) words into single line.

Comment: Just replace `\r?\n` (an optional carriage return and a  linefeed) with nothing, or with a space. That would work for both Windows and Unix/Linux style end of lines.

Comment: it working fine. but my task to keep single space to between two multiple joins. Thanks you LukStorms.